# EF Core use stored procedure to load related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have a data model like this:

```
public class Parent {
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public int ChildID {get; set;}
  public Child Child {get; set;}
}

public class Child {
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string AnotherProp {get; set;}
}
```

I also created a stored procedure to load the data for performance reasons:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetAllParents
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT p.ID, p.Name, p.ChildID, c.ID, c.Name
 FROM dbo.Parent p
 INNER JOIN dbo.Child c on c.ID = p.Child.ID
END
```

And I use EF Core to call it and load all Parents with their Child:

```
var parents = await _context.Parent.FromSqlRaw("exec GetAllParents").AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

This works fine but it doesn't load the related data e.g. the child property. Is there a way to tell EF how to map it columns to the related entities?

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#including-related-data

Comment: I do not see any benefits of this SP. It should be fast with LINQ also. And probably it will be more effective.

Comment: EF Core Power Tools can generate the mapping and method call for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SvyatoslavDanyliv suggested it needs less code to use EF classes. But if you need to use stored procedure you will have to add some more code.

Change the SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetAllParents
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT p.ID as ParentId, p.Name as ParentName, c.ID as ChilId, c.Name as ChildName
 FROM dbo.Parent p
 INNER JOIN dbo.Child c on c.ID = p.ChildID
END
```

and create a class for a sp result

```
public class SpResult
{
public int ParentId {get;set;}
public string ParentName {get; set;}
public int ChilId {get;set;}
public string ChildName {get; set;}
}
```

add to  db context

```
 public virtual DbSet<SpResult> SpResults { get; set; }

 modelBuilder.Entity<SpResult>(e =>
   {
  e.HasNoKey();
   });
```

and finally code

```
var spResult = await _context.SpResults.FromSqlRaw("exec GetAllParents").ToListAsync();

var parents=sp.Result.Select( i=> new Parent 
{
 ID = i.ParentId,
 Name =i.ParentName,
 ChildID =i.ChildId,
 Child= new  Child { ID= i.ChildId, Name=i.ChildName}
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks that helped! Is there also a way to load a list from the SP? Let's say Child would actually be a list of children?

Comment: Unfortunatelly you can return only 1 select set of records  from EF stored procedure.  Each record can have any kind of data that T-SQL allows. If you need to return several sets of data it's better to use a reader and Ado.net.

Comment: Since you have used public virtual DbSet<SpResult> SpResults { get; set; }, next time when trying to add-migration it will try to create table SpResults